# Yarn install says up to date, yet can't start rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, yarnpkg

I've been developing an app using Webpack, Vue.js and Rails. No problems for two months, but out of nowhere when I try to start rails console `rails c`, `yarn` complains that packages out of date:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Unknown language key integrityNodeDoesntMatch".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/maksimfedotov/vras/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check for documentation about this command.


========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install` to update.
========================================
```

Yet when I run `yarn install`:

```
yarn install v1.3.2
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.71s.
```

I've been looking through yarn and webpacker documentation, tried various `yarn` cleanup commands, but no luck.

Interestingly enough, I can still run the server, its only console that complains.

Comment: Did you try deleting `yarn.lock` and running `yarn install` again?

Comment: Have you tried yarn update ?

Comment: I haven't tried either, but this issue just went away. Not sure what happened...

Comment: I have the same issue with running `rails c` and `rails g ...`. Deleting node_modules and yarn.lock doesn't help

Comment: Please remember to try `spring stop` as a simple fix after every configuration change and before deleting anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an old issue, which has been resolved, so I am writing down what I did in the end:

Simply deleting `node_modules` usually solves the issue. If you are using spring, it also can mess this up, so consider running `DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails s` to see if that helps

Comment: Deleting node_modules didn't work for me, but disabling spring did. Is there a way to get spring and webpacker to play nice together?

Answer (score 17):

Try restarting spring by running `spring stop`.

This fixed the issue for me, and meant I didn't need to constantly prefix commands with the spring disable flag.

The above command stops spring: to check that it automatically restarted, run `spring status`.

Credit to [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1374#issuecomment-476128921) for the solution!

Answer (score 5):

You can add in the `config/environments/development.rb`

this configuration setting

```
config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false
```

It also it forget to check yarn integrity on every rails call, as migrations, launching consoles ..., in development environment

Answer (score 1):

This problem resurfaced in April 2021 due to compatibility issues between node-sass and node version 16.  ([I had similar problems here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67241196/5783745) and provide a similar answer to that below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67242989/5783745)).

So my solution is to downgrade node until version 16 is fully compatible.

Install node 14 with `nvm install 14`, then set it to the global default with `nvm alias default 14`.

Then:

1. Stop your rails server if it's running
2. Open a fresh new terminal window (so that `node --version` returns `14.x` (not 16)
3. Run `spring stop`
4. Delete `yarn.lock`
5. Remove existing node modules with `rm -rf node_modules`
6. Check that `node --version` returns 14. If it doesn't run `nvm install 14` again.
7. Now reinstall modules with `yarn install` (if you don't have yarn for node 14, install it with `npm install --global yarn`)
8. It should succeed!
9. Restart your rails server, and it will work!

Other useful info:

- [This](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1374) github issue - [this comment](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1374#issuecomment-605663098) in particular

Comment: The only thing I would add, as a possible extra, is to use a `.nvmrc` with the version added to it

Comment: @BenKoshy I should probably update this because I think node-sass library has been corrected since, so going to the most recent node version might work now (I’m speculating though)

Answer (score 0):

Try just `yarn install` then `rails c` again

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching branches which change `yarn.lock` and just want to run a rails console without having to keep running `yarn install` everytime you switch, you can add this to your `app/config/development.rb`

```
config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = ENV['SKIP_YARN'].nil?
```

Then when rails complains you can simply do this

```
SKIP_YARN=true rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this solve the problem.

```
rm -rf yarn.lock
yarn install
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `NODE_ENV=development yarn install`