# Force yarn.lock to generate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg, webpacker

I have a rails app, I deleted `yarn.lock` (due to some [complicated errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67253146/5783745)), but I would like to regenerate it.

I tried `yarn install -std:c++latest` and `yarn install --check-files -std:c++latest`. As far as I can tell, these commands succeed, but I don't see any new `yarn.lock` file.

Any ideas how to force it to be generated?

(open to hacky ideas - I am not so familiar with the inner workings of these package managers so I'm unclear how to solve)

#### Notes

When I run `yarn install --check-files -std:c++latest`, I see:

```
yarn install --check-files -std:c++latest
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
warning webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
```

Answer (score 2):

Run just: `yarn` from the terminal

Answer (score 2):

One reason a `yarn.lock` file would *not* generate is that `frozen-lockfile` was specified.  That option prevents creation of a lockfile.  You can check your `.yarnrc` to make sure it's not present.