# Mac M1 - Node Error - error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby-on-rails

I am using the Macbook M1 and facing the following issue while `yarn install`. I am trying to set up a rails 6 project that is using stimulusJS.

````
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:776:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
                                                 ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/fahadazeem/Data/Projects/golfpay360/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/16.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/fahadazeem/Data/Projects/golfpay360/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/fahadazeem/Data/Projects/golfpay360/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0```
````

Comment: What version of `node-sass` are you using? Prior to version 6.0.1, `node-sass` did not support Node 16. Suggest you either update `node-sass` or downgrade Node to v14.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: no template named 'remove\_cv\_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove\_cv'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241196/error-no-template-named-remove-cv-t-in-namespace-std-did-you-mean-remove)

Comment: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X Unsupported architecture (arm64) with Unsupported runtime

Comment: Note that `node-sass` was deprecated a long time ago, as explicitly called out on [its npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) and anyone who still finds this question while using `node-sass` should switch to [the `sass` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) instead.