# Heroku: Precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails application to heroku but heroku fails during assets precompiling. I precompiled assets locally and everything is working fine. I used following command to precompile assets locally `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. I am getting following errors in Heroku

```
          48 |    result = (fragment & 0x003) << 4;
             |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:52:2: note: here
          52 |  case step_B:
             |  ^~~~
       ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:62:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
          62 |    result = (fragment & 0x00f) << 2;
             |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:66:2: note: here
          66 |  case step_C:
             |  ^~~~
         ‘class utf8::invalid_code_point’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
         110 |       catch (utf8::invalid_code_point) {
             |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:114:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::not_enough_room’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
         114 |       catch (utf8::not_enough_room) {
             |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:118:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_utf8’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
         118 |       catch (utf8::invalid_utf8) {
             |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
         
         405 |   catch (std::exception) {
             |               ^~~~~~~~~
       ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_stringify(const JsonNode*, const char*)’:
       ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:424:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
         424 |   catch (std::exception) {
             |               ^~~~~~~~~
        
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/node.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/node.o ../src/libsass/src/node.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/operators.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/operators.o ../src/libsass/src/operators.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o ../src/libsass/src/output.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/parser.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/parser.o ../src/libsass/src/parser.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/plugins.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/plugins.o ../src/libsass/src/plugins.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/position.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/position.o ../src/libsass/src/position.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o ../src/libsass/src/prelexer.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/remove_placeholders.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/remove_placeholders.o ../src/libsass/src/remove_placeholders.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass.o ../src/libsass/src/sass.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass2scss.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass2scss.o ../src/libsass/src/sass2scss.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_context.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_context.o ../src/libsass/src/sass_context.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_functions.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_functions.o ../src/libsass/src/sass_functions.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_util.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_util.o ../src/libsass/src/sass_util.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_values.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_values.o ../src/libsass/src/sass_values.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/source_map.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/source_map.o ../src/libsass/src/source_map.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o ../src/libsass/src/subset_map.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o ../src/libsass/src/to_c.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o ../src/libsass/src/to_value.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o ../src/libsass/src/units.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o ../src/libsass/src/utf8_string.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o ../src/libsass/src/util.cpp
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o.d.raw   -c -o                 rm -rf "Release/sass.a" && cp -af "Release/obj.target/src/sass.a" "Release/sass.a"
         g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
             |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
             |                                      remove_cv
       /app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
         492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
             |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
             |                                      remove_cv
       /app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
         492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
             |                                                  ^
       /app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
         492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
             |                                                               ^~~~~~~
       ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
       ../src/binding.cpp:284:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
         284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
             |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
       ../src/binding.cpp:320:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
         320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
             |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:58,
                        from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
       ../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
       /app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/node.h:821:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
         821 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
             |                                           ^
       /app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/node.h:855:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
         855 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
             |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
         358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
             | ^~~~~~~~~~~
       make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_1c398fcd/node_modules/node-sass/build'
       gyp ERR! build error 
       gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_1c398fcd/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
       gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1097-aws
       gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_1c398fcd/bin/node" "/tmp/build_1c398fcd/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
       gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1c398fcd/node_modules/node-sass
       gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
       gyp ERR! not ok 
       Build failed with error code: 1
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Please scroll down to see the error message from the log. I have no idea what the error message means. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had the same issue, it looks like this has been handled before already. My steps to resolve:

`yarn upgrade @rails/webpacker --latest`

I had upgrade my version of node to 14.15.0--this may be different to you--using:

`nvm install 14.15.0` prior to getting the yarn update to work.

That was it.

Referenced:

[Heroku deplyoment asset precompiling failed on rails 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491693/heroku-deplyoment-asset-precompiling-failed-on-rails-6)

&

[error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241196/error-no-template-named-remove-cv-t-in-namespace-std-did-you-mean-remove)

Comment: You're my hero without cape!!! Thanks a lot